# How to show a part of a bitmap on a screen?

Tags: android

Now I want to make a effect,when my finger touch on a picture on the screen, the picture will be show from the top of picture to the position I touched exactly.Can you give me some advice to achieve this effect.Thanks a million,whether or not you will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution, but a clue:

You will probably need to implement your own animation which will scale / translate your image. There is a lot of tuts on [google](http://goo.gl/ZQNlD).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your clue.I think it could be better to custom a view that showed dynamically with finger's moving.How do you think of it?

Comment: @Sysphus I think what you want to do is typically an animation, but reading your comment, I'm not sure anymore. May be I didn't understand what you actually want to do :/

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.Let me describe it in more detail.A whole picture is showed on a screen,but now I want it will be showed partly with my finger's moving.First of all,the position of picture's top on the screen is fixed.Secondly,I begin to move my finger after touching on the area of picture showed,then the position of picture's bottom vary with my finger's position.And the position also is the position of a whole picture.So the picture you see is always a part of that whole picture.

Comment: @Sysphus ok I think I get it now. Indeed, you will need to Override onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent to do want you want, this is absolutely not an animation ^^.